# How to set datetime attribute when displaying the same time for multiple time zones?

Tags: html5, date-format

If I have a date output with multiple time zones such as this which I'm using for an events page:

```
Oct 30, 2021 - 07:00 AM AEDT, Oct 29, 2021 - 21:00 PM BST, 15:00 PM CDT, 16:00 PM EDT
```

Is there a preferred way to declare a datetime attribute for this string?

**Examples:**

*Just the first datetime entry*

```
<time datetime="2021-10-30 07:00:00 AEDT" >Oct 30, 2021 - 07:00 AM AEDT, Oct 29, 2021 - 21:00 PM BST, 15:00 PM CDT, 16:00 PM EDT</time>
```

*Every datetime entry*

```
<time datetime="2021-10-30 07:00:00 AEDT" >Oct 30, 2021 - 07:00 AM AEDT</time>, <time datetime="2021-10-29 21:00:00 BST" >Oct 29, 2021 - 21:00 PM BST</time>, <time datetime="2021-10-29 15:00:00 CDT" >15:00 PM CDT</time>, <time datetime="2021-10-29 16:00:00 EDT" >16:00 PM EDT</time>
```

*Or as I'm dealing with multiple time zones just show UTC*

```
<time datetime="2021-10-29 20:00:00 UTC" >Oct 30, 2021 - 07:00 AM AEDT, Oct 29, 2021 - 21:00 PM BST, 15:00 PM CDT, 16:00 PM EDT</time>
```

Is any of the above treatments acceptable, or is there an alternative approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of your examples would be valid.

Because you are displaying a single date/time for various time zones, I would suggest not using separate `<time>` tags for each time zone.  They are redundant and they take up extra bytes.

I like your idea of using UTC for the `datetime` rather than the first timezone. UTC is the time zone that computers are pretty much 100% guaranteed to understand, so it seems most appropriate for the machine readable version.

Comment: Thanks - I agree with you on the idea of using UTC, I think it's the cleanest solution.
I've run with that